# heroku run rails console hangs when input is provided via STDIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Using the [repo](https://github.com/heroku/ruby-rails-sample) provided by heroku, I could easily get one minimal working rails [app](https://salty-thicket-4387.herokuapp.com/).

On my local machine, I use heroku toolbelt to interact with the app:

```
$ heroku run rails c
Running `rails c` attached to terminal... up, run.7546
putsLoading production environment (Rails 4.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> puts 'hello'
hello
=> nil
irb(main):002:0>
```

I use `<Ctrl-D>` to exit, though it doesn't show on the terminal. So far so good.

However, I can not exit the console, if I start it by piping the command to `rails c`.

```
$echo 'puts 1' | heroku run rails c
Running `rails c` attached to terminal... up, run.3181
puts 1
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> puts 1
1
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> exit
```

Neither `<Ctrl-D>` nor `exit` works. It seems it's stuck forever.

In another shell, the relevant output for `heroku ps`:

```
=== run: one-off processes
run.3181 (1X): up 2015/02/03 13:46:45 (~ 6m ago): `rails c`
```

It would be great if someone could shed some light on this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems one bug in heroku command line tool. Ticket is created [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1409).

For now, I think @sadleb 's answer, appending `exit` to the command string, would be enough for practice.

EDIT:

By now, heroku team has proposed a workaround/solution, mentioned in above github issue:

`echo 'puts 1' | heroku run --no-tty rails c`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$echo 'puts 1; exit' | heroku run rails c`

I can't shed any light on why you have to do that though...